What I am doing wrong in contour integration?
Note: I have edited this post after reading the comments.
I am learning to integrate using contours. I tried testing this technique on following integral: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^{2}x}{x^2(1+x^2)} \, dx$$
I also know that above integral evaluates to $\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2e^2}$
Let $$f(z)=\frac{1-e^{2zi}}{2z^2(1+z^2)}$$
We will recover the target integral by taking Real part of the result later.
I made following semicircular contour to tackle the problem:

According to Residue theorem Integrating along this contour should equal to sum of all residues . Since there is only 1 pole in this contour at $z=i$
Therefore:
\begin{align*}
I&=2\pi i \lim_{z \to i} [(z-i) \times f(z)]\\
&=2\pi i \lim_{z \to i} \frac{1-e^{2zi}}{(2z^2)(z+i)}\\
&=2\pi i \times \frac{1-e^{-2}}{(-2)(2i)}\\
&=\frac{\pi(1-e^2)}{2e^2}
\end{align*}
Let the required Integral $I_1$.
From the diagram we can say:
$$I=I_1+C_R+c_r$$
Let's evaluate $C_R$:
$$
C_R=\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1-e^{2Rie^{i\phi}}}{2R^2e^{2i\phi}(1+R^2e^{2i\phi})} \, iRe^{i\phi}d\phi$$
Since we have $-e^R$ in the numerator , when $R \to \infty$ then $C_R \to -\infty$.
Let's evaluate $c_r$:
\begin{align*}
c_r&=-\lim_{r \to 0} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1-e^{2rie^{i\phi}}}{2r^2e^{2i\phi}(1+r^2e^{2i\phi})} \, ire^{i\phi}d\phi\\
&=-\frac{i}{2}\lim_{r \to 0} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1-e^{2rie^{i\phi}}}{re^{i\phi}(1+r^2e^{2i\phi})} \, d\phi\\
&=-\frac{i}{2}\lim_{r \to 0} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1-e^{2rie^{i\phi}}}{re^{i\phi}(1)} \, d\phi\\  \end{align*}      Applying L'Hospitals Rule
\begin{align*}
&=-\frac{i}{2} \lim_{r \to 0} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{-2ie^{i\phi}e^{2rie^{i\phi}}}{e^{i\phi}} \, d\phi\\
&= -\int_{0}^{\pi} 1 \, d\phi\\
&=-\pi
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
I&=I_1+(-\infty)-\pi
\implies I_1=\infty
\end{align*}
This result is clearly wrong. So where did I make a mistake?

$\left|\sin^2 (z)\right|$ is unbounded, this link here explains why. A good choice for $f(z)$ would be $\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{2z^2 \left(1+z^2\right)}$ so that you could bound the function nicely by taking the limit as $R$ goes to infinity, equate the real part on both sides of $\oint_{\text{contour}} = \text{the 4 integrals}$, and recover $\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2 \left(1+x^2\right)}$.

In $C_R$, $\left| {e^{2Rie^{i\phi } } } \right| = e^{ - 2R\sin \phi }  \le 1$, $0\le \phi\le \pi$. What $e^R$ are you talking about? It seems that you are unfamiliar with the complex exponential and sine functions.

@Gary Its not  $e^-R$ . its $e^R$. So that shoots to infinity when $R \to \infty$. Since $e^{2Rie^{i\phi}}=(e^R)^{2ie^{i\phi}}$. That inner $e^R$ I am talking about. Also this platform is for helping people and not for telling them they don't know anything.

$\left| {1 - e^{2Rie^{i\phi } } } \right| \le 1 + \left| {e^{2Rie^{i\phi } } } \right| = 1 + e^{ - 2R\sin \phi }  \le 2$ since $\sin \phi \ge 0$ for $0\le \phi \le \pi$. Sorry if my message seemed negative. I just wanted to suggest that you might want to look up and familiarise yourself with the properties of those functions.

Some further comments: Why not $e^{2Rie^{i\phi } }  = (e^{R + 16\pi i} )^{2ie^{i\phi } }$? $(e^R )^{ - 1 + i}  = e^{ - R} e^{iR} $ tends to $0$ even though $e^R$ tends to infinity.

I re-evalauted $C_R$ using jordan's lemma.
$$f(z)=\frac{1-e^{2zi}}{2z^2(1+z^2)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2z^2(1+z^2)}-\frac{e^{2zi}}{2z^2(1+z^2)}$$
Jordan's lemma can be applied on the latter part taking $a=2$ and $g(z)=\frac{1}{2z^2(1+z^2)}$ as g(z) is holomorphic on the upper half-plane.
So f(z) decays as $R \to \infty$
Also the first part decays when $R \to \infty$
So overall $C_R=0$
Putting this is the equation we get $$I=I_1+0-\pi $$
$$\implies I_1=I+\pi=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2e^2}$$ which is the correct answer.

+1 Nice :) Here's an alternate way to evaluate the contour integral over the small semi-circle integral. The following theorem says: "Suppose $f(z)$ has a simple pole at $z_0$. Let $C_r$ be the circular arc $\gamma(\theta) = z_0 + re^{i\theta}$ where $\theta \in [\theta_0, \theta_0 + \alpha]$. Then $\displaystyle\lim_{r \to 0^+} \int_{C_r}f(z)dz = \alpha i \mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=z_0}f(z)$."

What is name of this theorem?

I have no idea :P the text I was using doesn't provide a name.

In your estimate of $C_R$, you used $|\sin(Re^{i\theta})| \le 1$, which is false in general.  The sine goes rapidly to $\infty$ in the vertical direction!

The conventional thing to do is to take something like,
$$
f(z)=\frac{\exp(iz)}{z^2(1+z^2)}
$$
and take the imaginary part in the end.

My book writes $sin(\infty)$ as an "OSCILLATING number between −1
& 1". So why would it shoot to infinity? Can you please explain?

@PrinceYadav   He meant on the vertical direction, i.e. $|\sin(i\infty)| = |-i\sinh(\infty)| = \infty$.
